# When cell is selected, the backgound color of the button will change and then recorver

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a Customize *UITableViewCell* and there is a button within it, when I set the background color of the button to some color other than `Default Color`(which is `[UIColor whiteColor]`), then when the cell is selected, the background color of the button will change and recover when the selection highlight of cell is disappear.

How this happen and what to do to keep button's background color when cell is selected?

Comment: Could you look at the UITableViewCell's UITableViewCellSelectionStyle property in the interface builder? You should set it UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone if you dont want any changes when selected.

Comment: AFAICS, the thing is that the PO wants the background of the cell to change whereas the subviews should remain untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend inspecting the hierarchy of views you've got for your table view cells. It can be easily done: Run your app on the simulator -> Click "Debug View Hierarchy" (see the 1st image attached) -> Play around with the inspector (see the 2nd image attached).
[image]

[image]

**Update:** After digging for a while I got the following (please see the 3 screenshots below explaining the situation):
[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there's the internal call that clears the background colors of a cell's subviews named `_setOpaque:forSubview:`

Having that said, if you want to ensure the background color of your button remains the same you should implement the selection mechanism of your cell in the following way:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // here comes your custom color (it's assumed that myButton is a binded IBOutlet
    self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // or whatever else
}
```

It was unkind of UIKit. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I do as you said, and find the button's background color is absolute disappear

Comment: Correct, this will not solve the issue on its own, but there might be some unexpected things revealed. What is the superview (should be definitely one of UITableViewCell's subviews) of your button?

Comment: Overview:

Cell \
     |- ContentView \
                    |- Button
                    |- . . 

Cell is from xib, there is only one subview of cell called contentview, my button is in the contentview, as shows above.

Comment: That's quite normal. Ok, how did you set the background color for the button? I could help you if you shared the exact piece of code where you create cells and buttons and lay the 2nd on the 1st.

Comment: I create a simple project for this problem at  https://github.com/zeroleaf/IOS-DEMO/tree/master/puzzles/CellButtonTest . You can have a try :)

Comment: I will try to play around with it real soon. Cheers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90997/discussion-between-arthur-gevorkyan-and-zeroleaf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by recover. But you want to add a target action when adding the button to the cell using `- (void)layoutSubviews{}`. self in this case will be the custom table view cell. You want this code in the .m of custom tableViewCell class files.

```
          - (void) layoutSubviews {
              [self.button addTarget:self forAction:@selector(buttonPressedDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchedUpInside]
          }

    //Cell goes to this method once button has been pressed.
         - (void) buttonPressedDown{
              self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];//Replace withwhatever color you want.
         }
```

You could then edit buttonPressedDown with conditionals like this `if([self.backgroundColor isEqualTo:[UIColor redColor]])` on how to handle a button press if the background color has alread changed. Hoped this helped give more info on what you meant by recover when highlight of cell disappears. Not sure what you meant by that.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguous description of recover.   More detail, suppose   a button in the cell has a _green_ background color, when we select a cell, the cell has a highlight color which default is a light gray color.   And when this highlight color appear, the button's background green will disappear, and when the cell highlight disappear, the button's background green is come back. Much thanks.