# IOS: UICollectionView not showing full images in cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i am working in a project in which i am using UICollectionView for displaying images. i applied all the delegate methods and it works fine but the images shows in UICollectionView Cell is not shown full size only some part is shown 
please suggest me what changes i have to do in my code to show full images in UICollectionViewCell

I applied the following Codes:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface photos : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
    UICollectionView *_collectionView;
    NSMutableArray * imagearray;
    UIImageView *imgview;
}


@end
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    imagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"download3.jpeg", @"12045540_717548405011935_7183980263974928829_o.jpg" , @"download4.jpeg", @"download5.jpeg", @"download6.jpg", @"download12.jpeg", @"download13.jpeg", @"download16.jpeg",@"download3.jpeg", @"download6.jpg", @"download12.jpeg", @"download16.jpeg", @"download3.jpeg", @"12045540_717548405011935_7183980263974928829_o.jpg" , @"download4.jpeg", @"download5.jpeg", @"download6.jpg", @"download12.jpeg", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [imagearray count];
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    imgview = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imgview.clipsToBounds = YES;
    //cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgview];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];


    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20);
}
```

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit should be fine. Looks like a wrong frame on the image view itself.

Comment: i already used it but the result is same

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan how i set frame for imageview?

Comment: @iABP, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```

will repeat the imageView and you can't see the correct image . 
if your want to show an image view at your collection view cell,

1. add an UIImageView to your collectionViewCell
2. you can set image this UIImageView at CellForItem ->

   ```
   cell.imageview.image =[UIImage imageNamed :@"image name"];
   cell.imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   ```

if I didn't understand the question plz explain more.

Comment: i am using custom collection view for my application it is added and working fine but when i applied an array of images to display on cells it only shows a tiny part of images like if i uses 500*500 resolution image it only shows the top 160*160 part of the image i wand to show the full image in the cell. i only applied the above full code no storyboard so please review the code and answer it

Comment: I meant that don't use the cell background for assigning images, alloc init an UIImageView in your custom cell with equal frame of cell and set image this view at cell for item

Comment: when you use  "colorWithPatternImage" you can't see correct size of image

Comment: if your project is autolayout I can help with the imageView 's constraints

Comment: Problem is sort out now i didn't initialise my uiimageview thats why problem occurs now its working fine thanks for replying @engmahsa

Answer (score 1):

i didn't initialise my `UIImageView` thats why that problem occurs

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    imgview = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160, 160)];

    imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    //imgview.clipsToBounds = YES;

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgview];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Alright, so first of all make sure that the frame of your image view
   is correct. Here is my answer to another question but the idea of
   debugging the view hierarchy applies to your case as well (see
   screenshots there): https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861703/2799410.
2. If it's due to a wrong frame, just use:

   imgView.frame = CGRect(0.0, 0.0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/4, cell.contentView.bounds.size.height)

(it sets the frame of your image view to be located at the top left corner of your cell and take a quarter width).

Comment: There might be lots of reasons: incorrect layout constraints, wrong sizing of the cell itself and so on. Let's better have a chat. Go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2799410/arthur-gevorkyan and start a conversation.